# Methods to accept parameters and return a boolean

Tags: java

A bit lost here, nothing appears to be working. I have read back on the chapter about return methods and I just can't get it to work.

Basically I have to create a method that accepts a Park paremeter, I have a class called park that has setters and getters for the booleans, picnic, playground, tennis and pool, which basically get declared as true or false if the Park has them. It also needs return a boolean value if the park has picnic and playground facilities.

Here is what I have so far:

The Park class:

```
public class Park {

    private String parkName;
    private int parkAcres;

    private boolean picnicFacilities;
    private boolean tennisCourt;
    private boolean playground;
    private boolean swimmingPool;


    public String getParkName() {
        return parkName;
    }

    public void setParkName(String parkName) {
        this.parkName = parkName;
    }

    public int getParkAcres() {
        return parkAcres;
    }

    public void setParkAcres(int parkAcres) {

        if (parkAcres < 0 || parkAcres > 400) {
            System.out
                    .println("You have entered an invalid acre amount, it has been defaulted to 0");
            parkAcres = 0;
        }

        this.parkAcres = parkAcres;
    }

    public boolean isPicnicFacilities() {
        return picnicFacilities;
    }

    public void setPicnicFacilities(boolean picnicFacilities) {
        this.picnicFacilities = picnicFacilities;
    }

    public boolean isTennisCourt() {
        return tennisCourt;
    }

    public void setTennisCourt(boolean tennisCourt) {
        this.tennisCourt = tennisCourt;
    }

    public boolean isPlayground() {
        return playground;
    }

    public void setPlayground(boolean playground) {
        this.playground = playground;
    }

    public boolean isSwimmingPool() {
        return swimmingPool;
    }

    public void setSwimmingPool(boolean swimmingPool) {
        this.swimmingPool = swimmingPool;
    }

}
```

The exercise told me to create getters and setters for all of them, I haven't even got passed using one of them yet.

Here is the ParkTest class which has the methods to use these getters and setters:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestParks {

    static Park park1 = new Park();

    static String parkName;
    static int parkAcres;
    static boolean facilityCheck;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        parkInfo(park1);
        request();
        System.out.println("Test: " + facilityCheck);

    }

    public static void parkInfo(Park park) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the park name");
        parkName = userInput.next();

        System.out.println("Enter the size in acres");
        parkAcres = userInput.nextInt();

        park.setParkName(parkName);
        park.setParkAcres(parkAcres);


    }

    public static boolean request() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Do you want picnic facilities?");
        if(userInput.nextInt() == 1){
            park1.setPicnicFacilities(true);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }



    }

}
```

I don't quite get what the exercise wants me to do, it is asking me to check if both facilities are available and return the value. Everything I have tried, the value just ends up false every time. The book taught me this back in a chapter but really, it only shows the use with int/double variable and not boolean, no idea if this makes a difference, either way I am completely lost on how to do return methods...

Normally I would just prompt the user for what they want in the park, then use the setters to declare the booleans true, then use a simple if statement in a displayParkInfo() method using the getters to output the results to the console, it seems the task does not want me to do this though.

Comment: In your `setParkAcres` method you should `return` inside your `if` block, otherwise the field still gets set.

Comment: lol ok that has just added further confusion...my setParkAcres method in Parks is a void method and does not return anything. That method only takes the Acres entered, checks if they are in a valid range, then sets the corresponding variable to the users input value, if valid. if not it just defaults to 0.

Comment: You can `return;` nothing in a void method. That just stop method execution. You'll want to do that so that the `this.acres...` line doesn't get executed, otherwise your `if` check is not very useful (since the value is assigned anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class field is by default initialized to `null` for reference types, `0` for numeric types, and `false` for boolean types. Your field

```
static boolean facilityCheck; // = false
```

will be initialized to `false`. And since you aren't re-initializing it anywhere so it stays that way. You need to either set it to the return value of `request()`

```
facilityCheck = request();
```

or have that method itself set its value.

```
if(userInput.nextInt() == 1){
    ark1.setPicnicFacilities(true);
    facilityCheck = true;
} else{
    facilityCheck = false;
}
// return or not (change your method definition if not)
```

In the comment I made in your question

```
public void setParkAcres(int parkAcres) {
    if (parkAcres < 0 || parkAcres > 400) {
        System.out
                .println("You have entered an invalid acre amount, it has been defaulted to 0");
        parkAcres = 0;
    }
    this.parkAcres = parkAcres;
}
```

Is not very useful because whether or not the `if` condition evaluates to `true`, this line

```
this.parkAcres = parkAcres;
```

will get executed. You need to `return` inside the `if`.

```
public void setParkAcres(int parkAcres) {
    if (parkAcres < 0 || parkAcres > 400) {
        System.out
                .println("You have entered an invalid acre amount, it has been defaulted to 0");
        parkAcres = 0;
        return;
    }
    this.parkAcres = parkAcres;
}
```

The `return;` statement will stop execution of the method where it is and return execution to the caller of the method. This is unrelated to your other problem.

Comment: the first one you mentioned appears to be the way I am supposed to do it, I know how to do the other way as it is a simple change of variable. However the task makes it seem as if I'm suppose to use the return value of the method to set the variable to true or false.

Comment: @Gibbo Then that is exactly what you should do. `facilityCheck = request();`

Comment: Right ok well I have some sort of logical error somewhere else, regardless of the userInput == 1 or not, it still sets it to true. I will figure this out, thanks so far.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
facilityCheck = request();
```